# consulta SQL-oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

requiero seleccionar los registros de la tabla para aquellos registros **donde el salario esta entre el promedio** de salarios de todos los analistas(analyst) y el promedio de todos los vendedores(salesman)

la tabla es esta//salario es SAL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que tengo por ahora es la media de salarios por trabajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que procedimiento sigue?gracias

Comment: Hola. Así como no te daremos respuesta en imágenes, no nos des datos y tablas en imágenes. Eso implica transcribir para probar... Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué llevas hecho? Postealo porfa, para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes hacer una consulta que te permita obtener valores entre 2 rangos, solo que aqui no sabes el orden por lo que necesitaras un OR de betweens como el siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE (Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20) OR (Price BETWEEN 20 AND 10);
```

pero ahora llevado a tu codigo seria algo asi, primero, obtener promedio de salario analista,

```
(SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp GROUP BY job WHERE job = 'ANALYST')
```

luego ,obtener promedio de salario de vendedores

```
(SELECT AVG(sal) FROM emp GROUP BY job WHERE job = 'SALESMAN')
```

si lo anterior lo aplicamos en una QUERY similar a la de el ejemplo pero utilizando tus tablas y columas, el codigo seria el siguiente

```
SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        emp     
    WHERE
        (
            sal BETWEEN (SELECT
                AVG(sal) 
            FROM
                emp 
            GROUP BY
                job 
            WHERE
                job = 'ANALYST') AND (
                SELECT
                    AVG(sal) 
                FROM
                    emp 
                GROUP BY
                    job 
                WHERE
                    job = 'SALESMAN'
            )
        ) 
        OR (
            sal BETWEEN (SELECT
                AVG(sal) 
            FROM
                emp 
            GROUP BY
                job 
            WHERE
                job = 'SALESMAN') AND (
                SELECT
                    AVG(sal) 
                FROM
                    enp 
                GROUP BY
                    job 
                WHERE
                    job = 'ANALYST'
            )
        );
```

esa consulta debería devolver los registros que poseen salario entre esos 2 rangos

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: En esta cláusula: `WHERE (Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20) OR (Price BETWEEN 20 AND 10);`, el segundo `between` está de más; basta con el primero. De hecho, el segundo no va a devolver ningún registro, pues el 20 es mayor que 10, y el motor lo va a traducir en algo como: `or (price >= 20 and price <= 10)`, lo cual es una condición que ningún registro puede cumplir.

Comment: es porque no sabemos cual es mayor y cual es menor, no sabemos si debe ser entre A y B o entre B y A. ya que son valores dinamicos